# How come my pom.xml dependency isn't found for my Jenkins plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

My `pom.xml` has this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
</dependency>
```

When I use the `XMLSerializer` it throws an exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nu/xom/Node`

If I run the class locally and add the JAR to my classpath, everything works as expected. I'm running this class as a Jenkins plugin so I don't expect to be manually defining classpath - I figured that's what Maven should be handling.

It's important to note that Jenkins plugins require me uploading an `hpi` file that is created from Maven. It is not running based on the output `jar`. If I go on Jenkins box and manually put the xom JAR into `WEB-INF/libs`, it works. But obviously that means this plugin wouldn't for other people, which is self-defeating.

Here is minimal code causing error: https://github.com/DaveStein/parser-sample

The Readme has exact repro steps.

**Note on chosen answer**
The PR to my sample repo got me most of the way to where I needed to be. I did have a few other issues that had to get resolved, but the JSONObject conflict was the core problem. I took out all GlobalConfiguration as Jesse's PR suggested. The only other issue that might concern a future viewer was some glitch when using `xom` as explicit dependency while also using a higher version than 1.626 for `org.jenkins-ci.plugins` at the time of this post.

Comment: are you building an uber jar? You need to use the assembly or shade plug in to add your dependencies to the jar file.

Comment: @puhlen Are those plugins for java, or for context of Jenkins? I thought that Maven is supposed to manage dependencies on its own, so why would a plugin be required?

Comment: those are maven plugins.  In maven everything is done by a plugin, and the plugin to pack your dependencies into the jar.  Maven does handle this for you but you need to tell it that you want to (through adding and configuring the plugin)

Comment: @puhlen in the context of Jenkins, I must upload an hpi. These plugins are, as you said, about adding more content into the JAR. But my JAR is unused by Jenkins either way.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with an .hpi file.  Looks like a jenkins plugin file?  You don't need a jeninks plugin to build a fat jar.  What do you mean you are not using the jar?

Comment: @puhlen The HPI file is what I upload to Jenkins, so that is what (I guess) expands the java code to run. So I'm not directly using a JAR in that case.

Comment: Well if you are building an hpi instead of a jar you are doing something strange and non-standard.  You'll need to find out details specific to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins core bundles `json-lib`. (A forked copy, not that it matters for purposes of this question.) It does *not* bundle the optional dependency¹ XOM, whatever that is. When your plugin loads `XmlSerializer.class`, it gets defined by the class loader for Jenkins core, which then attempts to link against classes such as `nu.xom.Node`. Since this is not available in the defining loader of `XmlSerializer`—the Jenkins core class loader (more or less `jenkins.war!/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`)—you get an error. The fact that a class by that name *is* accessible in your plugin class loader is of no import, excuse the pun.

If your plugin needs to use its own versions of classes which are normally bundled in Jenkins core and exposed to plugins implicitly, then it needs to not only bundle those JARs (a regular `compile`-scoped Maven dependency suffices for that purpose), but to also use the [`pluginFirstClassLoader` option](https://jenkinsci.github.io/maven-hpi-plugin/hpi-mojo.html#pluginFirstClassLoader). Before attempting to do so, you had better understand Java class loading semantics thoroughly, or you will be lost in a maze of cryptic² `ClassCastException`s and `LinkageError`s.

By the way the `mvn hpi:run` command normally used to test plugin code iteratively does *not* simulate a realistic class loading regime. So if you are using `pluginFirstClassLoader` or any other tricks in this space, always double-check the resulting class loading behavior by (re-)installing an `*.hpi` in a sample Jenkins instance, for example using `/pluginManager/advanced`, or the `install-plugin` CLI command. Judging by your description, you were already doing that (and perhaps unaware of `hpi:run`).

¹The original sin here is use of `optional` dependencies. `json-lib` should rather have defined a distinct artifact `json-lib-xom` with hard dependencies on `json-lib` and `xom`. That would ensure that any given class loader can either see `XmlSerializer` *and* its dependencies, or neither.

²No progress on [JDK-6273389](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6273389), alas. Marked as a duplicate, but what it is a duplicate of, I am not sure. Theoretically Java 9 modules make questions like this obsolete—by imposing such onerous restrictions that applications like Jenkins could not use that module system to begin with.

Comment: See updated POM above... when I go to install the HPI, my Jenkins server says:

`WARNING: Failed to load my.package.MyClass$DescriptorImpl
jenkins_1  | java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of hudson/PluginFirstClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "net/sf/json/JSONObject"`

Comment: You had warned of other types of errors so I wonder if there is some conflict between my pom and the parent pom.

Comment: Not sure. But for starters you should be using a 2.x parent POM and not specifying a version of `maven-hpi-plugin`.

Comment: And the particular contents of your source code may matter. Really it is best to have a complete, runnable, *minimal*, self-contained test case published, for example on GitHub. Otherwise there is no way someone looking at your question can just try it for themselves—or offer a nontrivial fix.

Comment: Jesse, just added it https://github.com/DaveStein/parser-sample with exact steps in the Readme

Comment: And filed [PR 1](https://github.com/DaveStein/parser-sample/pull/1) showing how it can work. But this will not work in all cases. In general, if you expect to override core libraries which are used in API signatures that your plugin might encounter, as `json-lib` is, you would need to use the Maven Shade plugin to physically repackage your copies so there is no conflict.

Comment: Someone in comments had mentioned Shade... but if that's for repackaging JARs, how does that work for interplay of Maven + HPI + Jenkins? Looking at Shade made me think it wouldn't work in Jenkins context.

Comment: You can use Shade in a Jenkins plugin. Equivalent to taking the whole library you wanted to bundle, and copying its sources into your own source tree but under a different package name.

Answer (score 0):

please google "**noclassdeffounderror** vs **class not found**" , this error means the class dependency is in fact found but is not available in run time.

Try these steps:

- Run `mvn clean package` and `mvn clean install`
- Check if your maven environment is correct and has latest jars
- Check if the installed target project contains the required jars
- Check if dependency type is selected as runtime and not only as
  compile time in `pom.xml`

Here is an example of using runtime dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group-a</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>bar</type>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ah let me try the scope `runtime` in `pom.xml`. That could be it. And I see you updated your answer with that. Default is `compile`. Just was reading about it after your post :)

Comment: Switching to runtime changes error to `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nu.xom.Node`

Comment: Can you check the installed target and see if it contains the jar (step 4), Can you show the logs and exploded target war file

Comment: would that straight up be in target? or a subfolder? Locally, I see the jar for my project, but not the dependency jars. But it's not like I see the jar files there for my other dependencies that are working just fine.  In Jenkins, I see zero jars at all under target folder. When I invoke a goal in Jenkins I do `clean clover:setup test clover:aggregate clover:clover`

Comment: Note that this is a plugin where I uploaded the `hpi` after doing `mvn clean package` locally

Comment: Once you do maven mvn install, it will generate a war file and place it under .m2 repository. You can copy that and expand and check the contents of WEB-INF/lib directory and confirm if the dependency is there or not. Hope it is clear.

Comment: So I definitely see the appropriate JAR in `/.m2/repository/xom/xom/1.2.5`, which has `nu/xom/Node.class`. But it's not like I'm running install on Jenkins. The odd thing I see is that there is only 1.0 on my Jenkins box (1.0 also exists on my machine). Either way, I see the same class in the other version. 

So is my setup wrong? Or should I update my pom version to 1? Note that I don't explicitly call `Node` ever. I think 1.0 is from my `jet.sf.json-lib` dependency. I added 2.5 to try and get it in through brute force. So really unsure what to do now.

Comment: No you are looking at wrong place:

Lets assume your project id is project1 under com.abc.project package.
Once you do maven install you will get a war file (assuming its a web application), i.e. under .m2/repo/com/abs/project/project1/version/project1.war . copy and rename it to project1.zip and extract its content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153498/discussion-between-amitmah-and-dave-stein).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the local version of the XOM jar is not the same as the one that is used in your Maven version.  To verify use the `dependency:list` Maven command to list out all your dependencies.  Verify if the XOM dependency listed is the same version as the local jar.

Answer (score 0):

Probably error on jenkins occurred while this dependency has been loaded for the first time and now it's considered as complete. Try to remove dependency from jenkins' maven local repository and re-run. That might help you